# setting a measure value to NULL if a particular dimension is used in excel

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have an SSAS-2014 cube. I want to set a particular measure to NULL if a particular dimension is being used in either axis or the filter pane of a pivot table in excel. Now, the most intuitive solution, is to scope this measure to not work with the members of that dimension. Say, I don't want the measure to work with accounting period members, then I use the following MDX in the cube:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Test Measure] AS 1;

SCOPE([Measures].[Test Measure]);
SCOPE(DESCENDANTS([DIM Accounting Period].[Accounting Period Hierarchy].[All],,AFTER));
THIS = NULL;
END SCOPE;
END SCOPE;
```

This seems to work if I select one year in the filter of the pivot table. 
[image]

This seems good since excel send the following MDX back to the SSAS engine

```
SELECT NON EMPTY Hierarchize (
 {
  DrilldownLevel (
   { [DIM Production Period].[Production Month].[All Dates] }
   ,
   ,
   , INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS
  )
 }
)  ON COLUMNS
FROM [CUBE - Opex Analysis]
WHERE ( [DIM Accounting Period].[Accounting Period Hierarchy].[Accounting Year].[2015],
        [Measures].[Test Measure] ) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE
, FORMAT_STRING
, LANGUAGE
, BACK_COLOR
, FORE_COLOR
, FONT_FLAGS
```

Problem happens if I select two members in the filter pane, as shown in this image
[image]

and the reason for that seems to be related to the MDX that excel sends back to the engine. It encapsulate the items inside a subcube making the engine thinks that no accounting year is being selected. This is the MDX that excel uses:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY Hierarchize (
 {
  DrilldownLevel (
   { [DIM Production Period].[Production Month].[All Dates] }
   ,
   ,
   , INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS
  )
 }
)  ON COLUMNS
FROM (
 SELECT (
 { [DIM Accounting Period].[Accounting Period Hierarchy].[Accounting Year].[2015],
   [DIM Accounting Period].[Accounting Period Hierarchy].[Accounting Year].[2016] } ) ON COLUMNS
 FROM [CUBE - Opex Analysis]
)
WHERE ( [Measures].[Test Measure] ) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE
, FORMAT_STRING
, LANGUAGE
, BACK_COLOR
, FORE_COLOR
, FONT_FLAGS
```

Please note, That I also tried to use EXISTING trying to capture accounting years being used but I was having the same problem. Does anyone know a way to fix this?. I had a similar problem before, but implementing the solution I used here is overkill for performance [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33680421/change-the-context-with-subselect-mdx-from-excel-client)
I am using SSAS 2014 and Excel 2013

Answer (score 2):

Hm, the only solution I could envisage for subcube scenario is to create dynamic set on probed dimension as described in the article of referred question. Then for your scope add another sub scope([DIM Accounting Period].[Accounting Period Hierarchy].[All]) and count `DESCENDANTS([DIM Accounting Period].[Accounting Period Hierarchy].[All],,AFTER)` in this scope. Compare it with count of the dynamic set. If two do match - you are not inside subcube from subselect, otherwise you are.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but the dynamic sets solution is really killing the performance as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Ala, Sad but true. Have not tried SSAS 2016 yet, in 2014 there is not other way but dynamic sets to detect subcubes.